# SharePoint 2007 calendar event creation via email

Tags: 2007, calendar

I've SP Calendar with enabled incoming email.
If Security policy set to

> Accept e-mail messages based on list permissions

and user who sends a meeting request has Contribute permissions - it doesn't work.

If Security policy set to

> Accept e-mail messages from any sender

it does work.

Also if you have an Exchange account (which has the Email field as following: `SMTP:MyCal@MyDomain.com`) and specify it - it also doesn't work. However I do have the same calender where the last approach work.

Can you clarify what is missed? I just need to create an event based on the permissions.

Comment: Have you verified the said user(s) have contribute permissions to the calendar?  It sounds like they don't if it works ofr all senders and not based on permissions. It's a dumb question, but we need to ask.

Comment: @PirateEric As I've mentioned the user does has Contribute permissions. That's a weird part..

Comment: duh, sorry about that.  I read it 3 times and totally missed it 3 times.  4th time must be the charm.